# shapeshift jquery customize whit photos

Tags: jquery

Im trying to customize that jquery script but i cant.

The only thing i want to do is change the boxes to photos, like the kitty ones, but whit no options, but i cant do

http://mcpants.github.com/jquery.shapeshift/

thats the repository

```
(function() {

$(function() {
var $containers, child_count, filter_options, getRandomColor, renderChildren, renderPlaceholders;
$containers = $(".ss-container");
child_count = 5;
(renderChildren = function() {
  var weighted_colspans;
  weighted_colspans = [1];
  return $containers.each(function(container_i) {
    var colspan, elements, height, i, _i;
    elements = [];
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= child_count ? _i < child_count : _i > child_count; i = 0 <= child_count ? ++_i : --_i) {
        colspan = 209;
        height = 280;          
      elements.push("<li data-ss-colspan=" + colspan + " style='height: " + height + "px'><div class='position'><div>" + i + "</div></div></li>");        
    }
    return $(this).append(elements.join(""));
  });
})();
getRandomColor = function() {
  var color, i, letters, _i, _ref;
  letters = 'ABCDEF'.split('');
  color = '';
  for (i = _i = 0, _ref = letters.length; 0 <= _ref ? _i < _ref : _i > _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 5)];
  }
  return color;
};
(renderPlaceholders = function(type) {
  return $containers.each(function() {
    var $child, $children, background, height, i, width, _i, _results;
    $children = $(this).children().not(".credits");
    child_count = $children.length;
    if (type === "index") {
      return $(this).find(".position").show();
    } else {
      $(this).find(".position").hide();
      _results = [];
      for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= child_count ? _i < child_count : _i > child_count; i = 0 <= child_count ? ++_i : --_i) {
        $child = $($children[i]);
        height = $child.height();
        width = $child.width();
        switch (type) {
          case "fpoimg":
            background = 'url("http://fpoimg.com/' + width + 'x' + height + '?bg_color=' + getRandomColor() + '&text_color=444444")';
            break;
          case "placekittens":
            background = 'url("http://www.placekitten.com/' + width + '/' + height + '")';
        }
        _results.push($child.css({
          backgroundImage: background,
          height: height
        }));
      }
      return _results;
    }
  });
})("fpoimg");
filter_options = {
  minColumns: 3
};
$containers.shapeshift(filter_options);
$(".options ul.animation li").on("click", function() {
  switch ($(this).data("option")) {
    case "enable":
      filter_options.animated = true;
      break;
    default:
      filter_options.animated = false;
  }
  return $containers.shapeshift(filter_options);
});
$(".options ul.dragndrop li").on("click", function() {
  switch ($(this).data("option")) {
    case "enable":
      filter_options.enableDrag = true;
      filter_options.enableDrop = true;
      break;
    default:
      filter_options.enableDrag = false;
      filter_options.enableDrop = false;
  }
  $containers.trigger('ss-destroy');
  return $containers.shapeshift(filter_options);
});
$(".options ul.filtering li").on("click", function() {
  switch ($(this).data("option")) {
    case "hide":
      $containers.children(":visible").sort(function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
      }).first().hide();
      break;
    default:
      $containers.children(":hidden").sort(function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
      }).first().show();
  }
  return $containers.trigger("ss-rearrange");
});
$(".options ul.placeholders li").on("click", function() {
  renderPlaceholders($(this).data("option"));
  return $containers.shapeshift(filter_options);
});
$containers.on("ss-arranged", function(e, selected) {
  var modifier;
  modifier = $(this).find(".ss-dragging")[0] ? 1 : 0;
  return $(this).children().each(function() {
    return $(this).find(".position").text($(this).index() - modifier);
  });
});
$containers.on("ss-rearranged", function(e, selected) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------");
  console.log("This container:");
  console.log($(this));
  console.log("Has rearranged this item:");
  console.log($(selected));
  return console.log("Into this position:", $(selected).index());
});
$containers.on("ss-removed", function(e, selected) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------");
  console.log("This item:");
  console.log($(selected));
  console.log("Has been removed from this container:");
  return console.log($(this));
});
$containers.on("ss-added", function(e, selected) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------");
  console.log("This item:");
  console.log($(selected));
  console.log("Has been added to this container:");
  return console.log($(this));
});
$containers.on("ss-trashed", function(e, selected) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------");
  console.log("This item:");
  console.log($(selected));
  return console.log("Has been removed from the DOM");
});
return $containers.on("ss-drop-complete", function(e) {
  console.log("----------------------------------------");
  console.log("This container:");
  console.log($(this));
  return console.log("Has finished rearrangement after a drop.");
});
});

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much the bare minimum you need to get jQuery.Shapeshift working, and visible:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikemhz/tjAQN/

STYLE.CSS

```
ul.ss-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.ss-container li {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  height:120px;
  width:80px;
}

ul.ss-container li[data-ss-colspan="2"] { width: 170px; }
ul.ss-container li[data-ss-colspan="3"] { width: 260px; }
ul.ss-container li[data-ss-colspan="4"] { width: 350px; }

ul.ss-container li.ss-dragged-child {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: .7;
}

ul.ss-container li.ss-placeholder-child {
  background-color:grey;
}
```

SCRIPT.JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ss-container').shapeshift();
});
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery.Shapeshift</title>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<!-- Core Shapeshift & Touch Compatability Files -->
<script src="jquery.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.shapeshift.min.js"></script>

<!-- My Own Files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <ul class="ss-container"> 
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
        <li data-ss-colspan="1"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```